# bootstrap flex do not center the content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

bootstrap flex do not center the content

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-left"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-muted text-center justify-content-center" style="text-transform: uppercase;">comments</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap 4, somehow class `text-center justify-content-center` do not work, can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap 4 [justify classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content) need to be applied to the *row* (with the `d-flex` class),  not the column.

Shifting `justify-content-center` to the parent centers your elements as expected.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3 justify-content-center">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-left"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-muted" style="text-transform: uppercase;">comments</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

Note that this centers all elements. If you're looking for a 'left-middle-right' layout (so that only the middle element is centered), then you want `justify-content-between` instead:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3 justify-content-between">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-left"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-muted" style="text-transform: uppercase;">comments</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's also `justify-content-around` -- it really depends on the look you're going for, but it most likely is indeed `justify-content-between` :)